# Implement 0/1 knapsack problem in python using backtracking

Tags: python, algorithm, analysis, backtracking, knapsack-problem

I would like to display the maximum value possible given a Maxweigth and the indexes of items selected.
I would also like to count the number of recursive calls happening during the execution.

- random weight and value lists are generated using the generate function.
- vsol[] has the final list of item indexes selected
- temp[] holds the temporarily selected indexes
- values[] will hold the array of values of items
- weights[] will hold the array of weights of items
- solution after the Knapsack() will hold the max value it can have from the given weight(second argument of Knapsack())
  [image]
  **input**: values[] = [60,100,120], weights[10,20,30], maxWeigth = 50
  **Expected Output**: 220 [1,2]
  **output sited**: 0 [] for every input selected item indexes

```
import random
import copy

weights = []
values = []
temp = []
vsol = []
isSol = False
solution = 0
def Knapsack(i,max,value):
    for k in range(i,len(values)):
        if max > 0:
            if weights[k] <= max:
                temp.append(k);
                if (value+values[k] >= solution):
                    solution = value+values[k];
                    isSol = True
            if (k+1)<n:
                Knapsack(k+1,max-weight[k],value+values[k])
            else:
                if isSol == True:
                    vsol = []
                    vsol = copy.deepcopy(temp)
                    temp = []
                    isSol = False
                else:
                    temp = []
                    return
        else:
            if isSol == True:
                vsol = []
                vsol = copy.deepcopy(temp)
                temp = []
                isSol = False
            else:
                temp = []
                return
    
    

def generator(n):
    l = [];
    for i in range(n):
        l.append(random.randint(1,100))
    return l    
def main():
    n = 10 #number of random numbers
    weights = generator(n);
    values = generator(n);
    Knapsack(0,10,0)
    print(solution,vsol)
    
main()
```

I tried deep copying the temp list to vsol[].

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: i need to find the maximum value possible from the given weight

Comment: Still not understood ... Please add an example(basically show what you want to achieve).

Comment: reframed the question and added an example on what I need to achieve

Comment: Cool understood now... Also you want all recursive steps happening or only count? ( You want soln. with memoization or without memo.?)

Comment: count is enough and without memo. I would also like to see how memorization makes things better as well

Comment: Test it for larger cases. @M2Kishore I guess you have used phone for commenting That's why autocomplete converted memoization to memorization 

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import math
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**8)

c = 0
def knapSack(mW,w,v,n):
    # counter how many time recursive function is called.
    global c
    c += 1
    
    if(mW == 0 or n == 0):
        return [0,[]]
        
    if(w[n-1] > mW):
        return knapSack(mW,w,v,n-1)
        
    set1 = knapSack(mW-w[n-1],w,v,n-1)
    set2 = knapSack(mW,w,v,n-1)
    
    if(set1[0]+v[n-1] > set2[0]):
        set1[1].append(n-1)
        set1[0] += v[n-1]
        return set1
    else:
        return set2
        
val = [160, 100, 120]
wt = [10, 20, 30]
W = 50
n = len(val)
print("Knapsack Max & list:",knapSack(W, wt, val, n))
print("Total Recursive Steps: ",c)
```

[Python tutor](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) : use this simulator in future to learn what is happening.

Comment: I wrote my own code instead of modifying your code. Add generator function yourself.

Comment: If you face any difficulty pls tag me and then add a comment.